# How to stop running index like "/oak:index/cqTagLucene" in AEM

Tags: aem

How do I kill or stop running OOTB index. Actually, I want to add `excludepaths` then re-index again, which will be a quick operation for my use case.

Somehow this index has been re-trigger and running from 4 days (our system has millions of assets with .pdf files thats taking time). if we could exclude path and re-index again that will be solve our problem.

Comment: I am not sure, but check if this helps http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/indexing.html#abort-reindex

Comment: I have same question opened on Adobe forum , here is link https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2473189

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating index definitions might result in even more problems. Setting up exclude paths is possible, but it has side effects.
Please take a look at
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/troubleshooting-oak-indexes.html
https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#include-exclude

There you can find hints on how to abort (async) indexing, how to configure your indexes and more.

HTH,
Oliver